# IP checksum offload

Tags: network-adapter, tcpip, wireshark, udp, packet-loss

I recently updated to Windows 8 and get alot of invalid packet transfers. It says "Ip checksum offload?" (Wireshark) and most of my packets get lost. The checksum is 0x00. I also updated my NIC drivers, but this did not help. My internet worked well in Windows 7 with no problems at all.
Some websites do not work and some do. And when I open multiple tabs, they won't work at all: just one tab / website will load. Looks like the packet get timeout.

Both UDP and TCP are affected.

Answer (score 0):

To turn off these disturbing red lines in [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org), I suggest you to

1. Go to **Edit** > **Preferences**
2. Choose **Protocols** > **IPv4**, and uncheck "Validate IPv4 checksum if possible"